# Force capture all key presses into textfield. Barcode Desktop app using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, desktop

I am developing a little Barcode Reading application for desktops intended to run on Browsers.

I use a usb barcode scanner and the barcode scanner basically sends KEY STROKES based on the barcode, and emulates a ENTER / RETURN key press after the sequence.

The user can not see the display and relies only on the barcode beep to confirm DATA ENTRY into the software.

This is where the problem might occur. For the jQuery app to process the barcode, the textfield must be FOCUSED at all time.

I would like to ask if all or any of the following can be achieved using jQuery or something close to it, and how?

1. Keep a textfield in focus at all times
2. Capture ALL the keys regardless of any textfield being focused -
   where when I set the program to scanning mode, no textfield is shown
   but rather all incoming keys are being captured by a JS function or
   something like that.

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: If the user can't see the display, how do they know that the page is up and ready to accept a scan?

Comment: The user will first start up the software (webpage), when it's launched, the user goes round (wireless barcode reader) scanning items and he/she must not need to keep peeking at the screen at every scan.. i need the app to be reliable that when the user hears the scanner's "OK beep", then it should be somehow guaranteed that the system captured the barcode. I tested this and it's pretty reliable as long as the text field is focused, however there are occasions that the textfield loses focus (eg. AntiVirus popup, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve 1 by setting a `blur` handler on the element, preventing it to lose focus (possibly by refocusing on the element).

Number 2 could be done by setting a `keydown` (or `keyup` or `keypress`) handler on the document, meaning all key events are going to be captured.

Comment: is the blur handler reliable? what if the browser was minimized? or a new tab was opened? same w/ keydown, if the browser was somehow minimized, or loses focus? will it still work?

Comment: @BrownChiLD The blur handler will fire if the user leaves the page, but there is no way to cancel that. If you want that kind of control, you shouldn't be doing it from a webbrowser (although it will still be hard to take over the screen like that in other languages).

Comment: hmm, any suggestions on how i can go about this issue? I have to keep things in the browser .. I'm thinking perhaps I can do some sort of Audible OK BEEP from JQUERY to confirm barcode read.. and train user not to rely on the barcode reader's beep, but rather from the PC's beep.. but that seems crude lol. ..or perhaps I can use one of them WIN EXE wrappers and make a fullscreen win32 app afterwards. any other bright ideas perhaps?